# Using Spyder2 to calibrate monitor

Tags: display, monitor

Has anyone managed to use Spyder2 to calibrate a monitor in Maverick? I have seen some tutorials about argyll, but it seems complicated, and I'm not sure Spyder2 will work (and the tutos were oldish)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jcornuz.wordpress.com/2007/11/16/spyder-the-good-and-the-ugly/

Everything I know is in that post.

Yes, I know it's over three years old but thinking about it, how the display stack works really hasn't changed *that* much. ArgyllCMS plus some scripting for the Spyder *should* work.

I've been considering one of the cheaper ones for a while now. Almost all my work is online though so even if *I* have perfect calibration, it doesn't mean anybody else viewing my work will. For ~£60 I might give it a punt.

Comment: Thanks... I'll give it a try... but wanted to learn from past experiences and thus I asked ;). I would like to keep my Spyder2... in fact, I won't buy another one... so it works or my display remains uncalibrated.